# How to show percentage Of a value of a column based on another value of another column in pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have the below created pivot table.

| Governorate | Need Basic Edu | Need Bachelor Edu | Need Master Edu | Total Student |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gov1 | 10 | 20 | 30 | 60 |
| Gov2 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 90 |
| Gov3 | 50 | 60 | 70 | 180 |

Instead of showing number under the second, third, fourth columns, I need to show percentage as follow:

| Governorate | Need Basic Edu | Need Bachelor Edu | Need Master Edu | Total Student |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gov1 | 17% | 33% | 50% | 60 |
| Gov2 | 22% | 33% | 44% | 90 |
| Gov3 | 28% | 33% | 39% | 180 |

So each column is a percentage of column (Total Student) as per row (governorate)
Please note that every column is this pivot table is actually a separate column in raw data.